# How to add old Base SDKs in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4, base-sdk

Currently I'm using Xcode 4 with 4.3 Base SDK where I'm testing my apps on my iPhone 4.3.3 without any problem.

The problem is when I want to test on iPhone 4.2.1, it's throwing the error "CodeSign Error", and when I googled I found the solution is to change the Base SDK to match the device targeted for testing but couldn't figure out how to change the Xcode setting!

Please help on how to add an old Base SDK in Xcode 4.

Regards

Comment: Normally you don't need to install an old sdk you should only set the deployment target to the minimum iOs version you support. You can change the target by clicking on your project in Xcode and switch to the tab info for your target.

Comment: I tried what you told but its always throwing the "CodeSign Error"!

Comment: Then i think something in your settings or profile must be wrong. Make sure that the device you will test on is added to your provisioning profile and that the correct profile is selected in the codesign settings

Comment: I don't think I have anything wrong as I can test it with latest iOs. Please help guys.